# Does there exist a nontrivial prime power $q^k$ such that $\sigma(n^2)/n = q^k$ for some $n$?

Tags: divisibility, factoring, integers, divisor-sum, computational-number-theory

Let $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$ be the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$.

My question in the present post is closely related to [this one in MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404849):

**QUESTION**

> Does there exist a *nontrivial* prime power $q^k$ such that $\sigma(n^2)/n = q^k$ for some $n$?

I tried checking for examples of numbers $2 \leq n \leq {10}^6$ satisfying the divisibility constraint
$$n \mid \sigma(n^2)$$
using a Pari-GP script, via [Sage Cell Server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLyy_SyLM10lEwNAADHYXMNA0N3_wUjeLM9NxEjbw4I02dPE0FW1sFA02dgqLMvBKNPJ20xOQSkEZNIAAAYKsSpw==&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==):

```
for(n=2, 1000000, if((Mod(sigma(n^2),n) == 0),print(n,factor(n))))
```

Here is the output:

```
39[3, 1; 13, 1]
793[13, 1; 61, 1]
2379[3, 1; 13, 1; 61, 1]
7137[3, 2; 13, 1; 61, 1]
13167[3, 2; 7, 1; 11, 1; 19, 1]
76921[13, 1; 61, 1; 97, 1]
78507[3, 2; 11, 1; 13, 1; 61, 1]
230763[3, 1; 13, 1; 61, 1; 97, 1]
238887[3, 2; 11, 1; 19, 1; 127, 1]
549549[3, 2; 7, 1; 11, 1; 13, 1; 61, 1]
692289[3, 2; 13, 1; 61, 1; 97, 1]
863577[3, 2; 11, 2; 13, 1; 61, 1]
```

The Pari-GP interpreter of Sage Cell Server crashes as soon as a search limit of ${10}^7$ is specified.

[OEIS sequence A232354](https://oeis.org/A232354) lists $187$ additional examples.

I skimmed through the list of the first $199$ examples (not including $1$) in OEIS and noted that all of them are **odd**.  Additionally, here are the corresponding *integer* values for $\sigma(n^2)/n$ for $2 \leq n \leq {10}^6$:
$$\frac{\sigma({39}^2)}{39} = 61,$$
$$\frac{\sigma({793}^2)}{793} = 873 = {3^2} \times {97},$$
$$\frac{\sigma({2379}^2)}{2379} = 3783 = 3 \times {13} \times {97},$$
$$\frac{\sigma({7137}^2)}{7137} = 11737 = {11}^2 \times {97},$$
$$\frac{\sigma({13167}^2)}{13167} = 26543 = {11} \times {19} \times {127},$$
$$\frac{\sigma({76921}^2)}{76921} = 85563 = {3^3} \times {3169},$$
$$\frac{\sigma({78507}^2)}{78507} = 141911 = 7 \times {11} \times {19} \times {97},$$
$$\frac{\sigma({230763}^2)}{230763} = 370773 = {3^2} \times {13} \times {3169},$$
$$\frac{\sigma({238887}^2)}{238887} = 417263 = 7 \times {11} \times {5419},$$
$$\frac{\sigma({549549}^2)}{549549} = 1155561 = 3 \times {11} \times {{19}^2} \times {97},$$
$$\frac{\sigma({692289}^2)}{692289} = 1150347 = 3 \times {{11}^2} \times {3169},$$
$$\frac{\sigma({863577}^2)}{863577} = 1562185 = 5 \times {97} \times {3221}.$$

(I did the computations one at a time using WolframAlpha.)

Note that $61$ is prime.  However, it is **not** a nontrivial prime power.

I was hoping somebody with more computing power (and better programming skills) could automate the computation and thereby yield my desired result, if there is one at all.  (I would be content if this computation were done over this [list in OEIS](https://oeis.org/A232354/b232354.txt).)

Thank you!

Comment: This inquiry is also related to this [answer to a closely related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4370431/28816), which currently has a pending bounty.

Comment: How large is the search range in OEIS ?

Comment: Hold on, let me check, @Peter.

Comment: Less than $6.8 \times {10}^{12}$, @Peter.

Comment: That is a huge search limit ! If no solution is within this search limit, I do not expect a solution at all. Let us think about useful restrictions for $n$ ...

Comment: My computations above are only for $2 \leq n \leq {10}^6$, @Peter.  Apparently, the closest solution that we could get to $\sigma(n^2)/n = q^k$ *is only when* $q = 61$ and $k = 1$.  But then, we require $k > 1$ in order for $q^k$ to be a *nontrivial prime power*.  So I conjecture that there might be no solutions to my computational search problem.  Alas, I have no proof!  T_T

Comment: I checked further and manually computed and then factored the relevant quotients $\sigma(n^2)/n$ (using WolframAlpha) for ${10}^6 < n \leq {10}^8$, and did not find any solutions, @Peter.  (No further instance with $q$ prime and $k = 1$.)

Comment: My routine needed quite long for the humble range upto $n=10^8$ , no integer which is a perfect power appeared here, I did not doublecheck whether another prime occurs. We need criterions ($n$ must be odd but this does not help much) which I think the OEIS-author used as well to accelerate the search.

Comment: There is already a list of the first 199 $n$ such that $2 \leq n \leq {6.8} \times {10}^{12}$ [here](https://oeis.org/A232354/b232354.txt).  We only need to check for nontrivial prime-power values of $\sigma(n^2)/n$ for such $n$ in that list, @Peter.

Comment: I mean, I would be content with a check done in that range, over that [list](https://oeis.org/A232354/b232354.txt), @Peter.

Comment: Then it looks more like programming question (for stack overflow?)... Anyway I have loaded the list into Maple and checked that only $n=39$ there leads to single $p^e$ component.

Comment: @Sil:  For the record, $n=39$ does lead to $\sigma(n^2)/n = p^e$, where $p=61$ and $e=1$.  Thank you very much for your time and attention!  =)

Comment: @Sil:  Please flesh out your [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4375397/does-there-exist-a-nontrivial-prime-power-qk-such-that-sigman2-n-qk#comment9149314_4375397) into an actual answer, so that I could upvote.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I would be content if this computation were done over this [list in OEIS](https://oeis.org/A232354/b232354.txt)

Quick & dirty Maple code below checks that only $n=39$ in the list above corresponds to a prime power $\frac{\sigma({39}^2)}{39} = 61$.

```
vals:=[seq(v[2],v in readdata("b232354.txt",[integer,integer]))]:
for n in vals do:
  m:=NumberTheory:-sigma(n^2)/n:
  ifs:=ifactors(m)[2]:
  comps:=nops(ifs):
  if comps=1 then:
    print(n,ifs[1][1],ifs[1][2]):
  fi:
od:
```

Output:

```
39, 61, 1
```

Though I don't think this helps to conclude anything (that's why this was originally posted just as a comment), because even if the list covers all $n\leq 677004885711$, it is still a list with just $200$ elements.  $\sigma(n^2)/n$ being and integer is strict by itself, so adding another condition (it being a prime power) can simply lead to larger example (I am sure someone here could provide a heuristic for this). I don't think you can move on without understanding or at least restricting the $n$ for which $\sigma(n^2)/n$ is an integer.

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, and your answer.  I actually predict that $61$ does divide an odd perfect number, which led me to this inquiry.  (I think the proof can be done via a factor chain implementation.)  That $61$ does divide an odd perfect number $q^k n^2$ with special prime $q$ (yes, using the same notation as in my original post here) will then result to a contradiction, @Sil.

Comment: My apologies for being stubborn, @Sil, but could you check (via Maple) what is the *proportion* of numbers $n$ satisfying $n \mid \sigma(n^2)$ and ${61} \mid n$, **provided** $n$ is in [this list](https://oeis.org/A232354/b232354.txt)?  I conjecture that this percentage is at least $90 \%$.  (I do not have Maple installed on my machine, and I do not want to install a pirated copy.)  Thanks!

Comment: @ARNIEBEBITA-DRIS All of them satisfy $n \mid \sigma(n^2)$ by definition, and $67$ of them satisfy $61 \mid n$.

Comment: Thanks for checking, @Sil!